# Pandas to_datetime show format dont match

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

i think i have entered the format correctly.Shows value error

[image]

Comment: I would guess that not all values in that column share that format... but it is not possible to tell from the provided screenshot. Also, try passing `infer_datetime_format=True`

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead post the code as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @DavidErickson Yes your guess is correct! I actually needed to make a extra column to make an extra "Month" column to do some analysis.I later  sliced the **month** from **Order Date** and it served me the purpose.

Comment: @Scratte apperently this was my first post on stackoverflow. I will be careful from now on

Answer (score 0):

please check the following code:

```
df['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'], format='%Y%m%d').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

And if you want to format it to other date and time formats change the stftime() and please go look through the link for the other formats
[strftime() formats](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)